# Unwanted switching noise on the output of the MCP16417 (DC-DC, step-up converter)

Tags: dc-dc-converter, noise, step-up

I want to use the [MCP16417](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP1641X-Family-Data-Sheet-DS20006394C.pdf) step-up DC-DC converter for a low power battery powered project. Before implementing the design on a PCB I wanted to try the chip and built the circuit (top circuit on page 2 of the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP1641X-Family-Data-Sheet-DS20006394C.pdf)) on a breadboard (I use the MCP16417 in a MSOP form factor and soldered it to a adapter board). Unfortunately I get lots of noise on \$V_{\mathrm{out}}\$ (see pictures below).

[image: Vout, AC coupled, 1ms/, 100mv/, 10kOhm load]

[image: Vout, AC coupled, 20us/, 100mv/, 10kOhm load]

[image: Vout, AC coupled, 1us/, 100mv/, 10kOhm load]

Compare to fig. 2-31 on page 12 of the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP1641X-Family-Data-Sheet-DS20006394C.pdf).

I used an axial inductor and an \$10\,\mathrm{k\Omega}\$ axial resistor as a load. All connections on the breadboard (and the leads of the inductor) were shortened as much as possible.

Why do I see switching noise on \$V_{\mathrm{out}}\$? What can I do to make smaller? Is it just a problem when implemented on a breadboard (parasitic inductance/capacitance & coupling)?

Comment: *All connections on the breadboard (and the leads of the inductor) were shortened as much as possible.* I congratulate you with the fact that you got this even working on a **breadboard**! On a breadboard you will have longer traces and contact resistances that very often will prevent a DCDC converter to work at all. DCDC converters are **very sensitive** to the circuit layout, similar to RF circuits. If you build this on a PCB with a small layout and proper soldered connections, the switching noise is bound to be much lower.

Comment: *Is it just a problem when implemented on a breadboard* Yes, very much so. Note how there's a PCB layout example in the datasheet. Follow that, use the suggested components (inductor having high enough saturation currrent and capacitors with proper ESR) and you should have no noise issue.

Comment: Or you could try soldering it together 'manhattan style' ie solder parts together on the pins etc. It can be quite compact if you use SMT parts. Pay very close attention to the specs of the inductor and caps - use what the datasheet suggests. Component spec is VERY critical.